# How to push to an external array using Async.Whilst

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js, asynchronous

I'm trying to retrieve data from a service and store the results in an array for storing as a JSON, due to the structure of the data that i'm using, I need to nest `Async.Whilst` in this way:

Code:

```
var async = require('async');
var response = {};
async.whilst(function(){
    if(category <= externalCategory){
        category++;
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
},function(outerCallback){
    response[category] = [];
    async.whilst(function(){ 
        if(data == "pass"){
            return true;
        }else{
            //retry
            return false;
        }
    },function(callback) {
        var data = {
            //Retrieved data
        };
        response[category].push(data);   
        callback();

    },function () {
        outerCallback();
    });
},function(){
    next(null, response);
});
```

As I mentioned, i want an Object to save it in a JSON on my database, something like this:

Expected Result:

```
response:{
    0:[dataA, dataB],
    1:[dataC, dataD, dataE],
    2:[dataF],
    3:[dataG, dataH]
}
```

But, i keep getting all the Object filled with the last value on the array that i pushed:

Actual Result:

```
response:{
    0:[dataB, dataB],
    1:[dataE, dataE, dataE],
    2:[dataF],
    3:[dataH, dataH]
}
```

I'm new to asynchronus programming in Node.js, so I'm getting really confused about nesting async functions and why this happens, any help or alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

I hope your problem may solve by using 'eachOfSeries' of async in which you get the index value , so that you can avoid nested async and eachOfSeries is serial in action . so don't worry about asynchronus

https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#eachOfSeries